# How come Pisano periods develop this way for$\mod 2^m$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I came across this fun little math / programming problem.

[image]

*The programming language is Java*

Now, to shortcut a few things...

- The `n1 = n0 + (n0 = n1))` line affects a Fibonacci sequence.
- The loop is flawed, because `i` never increments
- `int` in Java is a 32 bit number, and overflows gracefully, not resulting in any exception or program crash

Hence, we get a Fibonacci sequence that eventually loops, thus having a [Pisano period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period). And the actual math problem is: how many unique numbers in the $-2^{31}$ to $+2^{31}-1$ range do we hit before we loop?

So, attacking the problem, I expanded the program to simply try this out, on the sequence...

- $x_0 = 0$
- $x_1 = 1$
- $x_n = (x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}) \mod 2^m$

...for $m = [2..30]$ (which is as far as I got before the program flaked out) and see how many unique numbers I hit.

And a very interesting trend showed itself...

[image]

*Green is actual runs, yellow is extrapolation.*

The columns are (from left to right):

- "Bit cap" is $m$, the number of bits used to represent $n_1$
- "Period" is the Pisano period when using $m$ bits to represent $n_1$
- "Unique" is the amount of unique numbers the sequence visits before looping back to $0, 1$ when using $m$ bits to represent $n_1$
- "Time (ms) is the execution time in milliseconds; how long it took for the program to go through one Pisano period
- "Period increase" is the relative increase compared to the line above; the ratio between the period on this line, and the period on the line above
- "Unique Increase" is the relative increase compared to the line above; the ratio between the amount of unique numbers on this line, and the amount on the line above

So, instantly it becomes obvious that there are patterns here.

- The Pisano period follows the sequence [A003945](https://oeis.org/A003945), or $2^m * 3 / 2$
- The number of uniques, from $m \geq 5$, follows the sequence [A175805](https://oeis.org/A175805), or $2^{m} * 21 / 32$, or $2^{m-5} * 21$

Question: why is this? Can this be proven? Does my extrapolation for $m = 31$ and $32$ hold?

Comment: What do column names in the results table exactly mean?

Comment: @Aig Post edited to include this information.

Comment: I would throw out everything programming-related. Everybody knows what Fibonacci is, and the details of particular implementation are hardly important.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Perhaps you should read the whole post before commenting — you obviously did not — because the implementation details makes this into an interesting math problem.

Comment: @MichaelK I have read the post and it does indeed contain an interesting math problem, which reads: _"How many unique numbers are there in a Pisano period modulo $2^n$? The apparent pattern is such-and-such; why is this?"_ Are the implementation details really all that necessary?